# spark - any way to execute a hook after worker finished processing partition?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm no expert in spark, so my apologies if I'm way off.

We are using apache spark to process different sections of a large file simultaneously. We don't need any aggregations of the results. The problem we are facing is that the worker will process records one by one and we'd like to process them in groups. We can collect them in groups, but the last group will not be processed as we get no information from spark that it is processing the last record. Is there a way to get spark to call something after processing of a partition is completed so that we could complete processing of the last group?

Or maybe a totally different way of approaching this?

We are using java, should you decide to provide some code examples.

Thanks

Comment: How about spark listeners?

Comment: you can use `foreachPartition` on the dataset/dataframe (but this code will be executed on the executors)

Comment: That worked great as far as processing records. Thank you. Now there is another problem. I was expecting my rdd to be sliced up among workers with all workers getting pieces of it, processing them in parallel. Instead, each worker gets the entire dataset and they work in sequence. One finishes and at that point another one gets started. They all do full amount of work. 

The code is like this:
`input.foreachPartition(new PartitionIterator());`

`public void call(Iterator<String> it) {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            processLine ( it.next() ) ;
        }
    }`